# How to improve performance using declarative manner instead of LINQ-to-Objects?

Tags: c#, linq

Let’s look at LINQ-to-Objects. How many inefficiencies are introduced by this code?

```
public object GetObjectToSerialize(object value, Type targetType)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] setToNullProperties;

    if (!_typeToPropertyMap.TryGetValue(type, out setToNullProperties))
    {
         var allPropeties = type.GetProperties();
         var passwordProperties = allPropeties
                                  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                                  .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Password")).ToArray();

         var passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute = passwordProperties
             .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any());

          if (passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute.Any())
          {
              throw new InvalidOperationException();
          }

          var propertiesWithEncryptedAttribute = allPropeties.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any());
          setToNullProperties = passwordProperties.Union(propertiesWithEncryptedAttribute).ToArray();

          _typeToPropertyMap[type] = setToNullProperties;
     }

     foreach (var property in setToNullProperties)
     {
           property.SetValue(value, null, null);
     }

     return value;
}
```

I'm wondering about to many `.Where` `.toArray` `.Union`.

For example, the `ToArray` method doesn’t know the size of the output, so it must make many allocations. If we have array of `int`s instead of `PropertyInfo` it’ll start with 4 elements, and then keep doubling and copying elements as necessary. And we may end up with excess storage. If we end up with `33,000` elements, for example, we will waste about `128KB` of dynamic storage (`32,000 X 4-byte ints`).

Also when I find `passwordProperties` there are two delegate object allocations, two for the call to `Enumerable.Where`. These delegates point to potentially two distinct closure objects, each of which has captured enclosing variables. These closure objects are instances of new classes, which occupy nontrivial space in both the binary and at runtime. (And of course, the arguments are now stored in two places, must be copied to the closure objects, and then we must incur extra indirections each time we access them.) In all likelihood, the `Where` operators are going to allocate new `IEnumerable` objects.

How can I improve code by using declarative manner (because it’ll just get faster as the compiler and runtimes enjoy new optimizations)?

Comment: `If we end up with 33,000 elements` if you run this on a type that has 33.000 properties of type string that contain "Password" in their name, your problem is **not** Linq.

Comment: The code inside the `if` is executed once for each type. I don't see any problem there. Even if it is 2x slower than necessary, it is still fast enough, and executed rarely enough (disclaimer: I wrote that code :-) )

Comment: Why do you need reflection? Maybe finding the reason could help you speed up things.

Comment: I totally agree with @xanatos. Also would like to mention that none of the used LINQ constructs introduces closures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside the if is executed once for each type. I don't see any problem there. Even if it is 2x slower than necessary, it is still fast enough, and executed rarely enough (disclaimer: I wrote that code :-) )

BUT you asked how to speedup the code... You could remove nearly all the LINQ:

```
public object GetObjectToSerialize(object value, Type targetType) 
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] setToNullProperties;

    if (!_typeToPropertyMap.TryGetValue(type, out setToNullProperties)) 
    {
        PropertyInfo[] allProperties = type.GetProperties();

        var setToNullProperties2 = new List<PropertyInfo>(allProperties);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in allProperties) 
        {
            bool isEncrypted = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any();
            bool isPasswordProperty = false;

            if (!isEncrypted) 
            {
                isPasswordProperty = property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.Name.Contains("Password");

                if (isPasswordProperty) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }

            if (isEncrypted || isPasswordProperty) {
                setToNullProperties2.Add(property);
            }
        }

        _typeToPropertyMap[type] = setToNullProperties = setToNullProperties2.ToArray();
    }

    foreach (var property in setToNullProperties) 
    {
        property.SetValue(value, null, null);
    }

    return value;
}
```

The real speedup would be to transform the code in an `Expression` tree generator, so you would remove the repeated reflection (the `SetValue` part). The problem is that generating the `Expression` tree and compiling it is quite slow, so unless you use `GetObjectToSerialize` hundred of times on the same `Type` then you won't have a speedup.